# Remove leading characters with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with field ID.

Here are some sample values:

1. 0001
2. 0002
3. 990003
4. 990004
5. 880005
6. 880006
7. 888006

I have a point where im fetching this records and i need to cut out the 99/88 (well its a pre-known prefix in my case its either 99 or 88 ... keep in mind that a valid id is also lets say 888888 that needs to be converted to 8888!.

I am aware that if all records had leading 99 or 88 i could use:

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 2) AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

How would i include a condition if there is leading 99/88 do the trim else not?

The expected output would be:

1. 0001
2. 0002
3. 0003
4. 0004
5. 0005
6. 0006
7. 8006

The function should be part of the select query and not a standalone query (example of the problem - field ID)!

```
SELECT
ISNULL(ProcId,0) ProcId,
ISNULL(ID,'') ID,
...
```

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: @techdo: The expected output is clear. Maybe you should re-read the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT case when mycolumn >= 880000 
            then RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 2) 
            else mycolumn
       end AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

or

```
SELECT case when mycolumn between 880000 and 889999
            then MyColumn - 880000 
            when mycolumn between 990000 and 999999
            then MyColumn - 990000 
            else mycolumn
       end AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

Comment: could you please explain how would i do it for 99 and 88 in the same query?

Comment: SELECT case when Id >= 880000 or Id >= 990000
            then RIGHT(Id, LEN(Id) - 2) 
            else Id
       end AS MyTrimmedColumn from MyTable

Comment: this looks good, now i just need to focus and figure out how safe it is :)

Comment: You can do that too. But what error are you getting with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 2) AS MyTrimmedColumn from table-name 
where id like '99%'
```